# Unable to click on a button which is part of IFrame using C# webdriver

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have c# webdriver configured for my Visual Studio 2010. I want to clcik on a          button "Install" from the Iframe. I am writing c# code to click on Install button from this IFrame.

Here is the HTML code...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<"pt1:pt2:mvtiframe" class="gradbg af_inlineFrame p_AFFlow" frameborder="0"   onload="AdfDhtmlInlineFramePeer.__iframeLoadHandler(event)" src="some url" style="width:700px; height:360px" _adfloaded="1">
<html>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left; height: 35px" colspan="3">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>
<a class="imageButton" onclick="OnNextButtonClick()" target="_blank" href="http://google.com/abc.asp">
<span>Install</span>
</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying with below code to click on "Install" button. But does not work. It says could not locate the element.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Install")).Click();
```

Tried with Xpath but i don't get the Xpath for Install button which is part of the IFrame.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the "Name" of the element is not "Install"
Install is the text for the button.

I would try some Xpath like this: `"//a[@class='imageButton']"`

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[@class='imageButton']")).Click();
```

If that's your page source, you should be able to find the element using that class.
This is all assuming that your `SwitchTo().Frame` is working as expected.

Also, if possible, I would really recommend putting a name or ID on that iFrame instead of using index. It will be more reliable in the long run, if the page changes.